# Is go if/for/func block open brace position required to be on the same line?

Tags: go

Does a go **block** following a for, func or if statement have to have the opening brace on the same line? I get a compile error if I move it down but I can't see in the language spec where they show that a block has to be structured like that.

> A block is a sequence of declarations and statements within matching
>   brace brackets.
>
> Block = "{" { Statement ";" } "}" .
>
> IfStmt = "if" [ SimpleStmt ";" ] Expression Block [ "else" ( IfStmt |
>   Block ) ] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#semicolons), because of semicolon inference:

> One caveat.
>   You should never put the opening brace of a control structure (if, for, switch, or select) on the next line.
>   If you do, a semicolon will be inserted before the brace, which could cause unwanted effects. Write them like this:

```
if i < f() {
    g()
}
```

> not like this:

```
if i < f()  // wrong!
{           // wrong!
    g()
}
```

---

As [jnml](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065241/jnml) comments,  the [language syntax is correct for blocks](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks).
But *combined* with [Semicolon injection](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons), it means you should really:

- always put the brace on the same line than the if statement (or the '`if`' won't do what you think it should)
- actually, always use [`gofmt`](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) and don't think about it (Preferably, gofmt your code each time you save it in your editor. It is fast and will make your code consistent with the rest of *any* Go code out there)

Even the Go compiler will enforce that "same line for brace" rule, to avoid any unforeseen side-effect.
So the language reference doesn't say where to put the brace, but both `gofmt` and the compiler will make sure it is correctly placed for a `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Von! Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like the go people have a Language Reference in formal EBNF style that does not fully define the language.

Comment: @Scooter: The EBNF is correct, it defines the language syntax. Semicolon injection defines what happens to the token stream before syntax analyses are performed. In short, language specs work as a unit. Any single part of them is not enough to "fully define the language".

Comment: @Scooter In this case, this isn't a lack of definition, rather a consequence of semicolon inference. You *could* put the brace on the next line (since the Ref doesn't say otherwise), BUT that would result in 99,99% of the times in the wrong program (it wouldn't do what you think it should). This is why [`gofmt`](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) is the greatest invention of all time. Associate `gofmt` with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> save action of your editor, and you won't have to think about it (brace positioning) ever again.

Comment: @VonC In my experience, if I move the brace down I always get a compile error.

Comment: @jnml I haven't heard that an EBNF is allowed to not completely define the syntax of the language. Wikipedia says it is a formal way describe computer programming languages. Not a formal way to "mostly" define" or "partially define". Any links to backup EBNF as a partial way to define syntax that  may have to be supplemented by other documentation?

Comment: @Scooter Again, this isn't a definition issue: you could put the '{' on the next line if you want. It just won't make the `if` execute the next block (because a semicolon will be injected, making the if execute "empty block" if its condition passes. This is why both `gofmt` *and* the compiler prevent you to do so.

Comment: @Scooter I mean, EBNF is a notation for "*Context*-free grammars" after all. To specify that the block should be, *in the context of a `if` statement*, on the same line that said `if`: that would sort of defeat the purpose of "context free"...

Comment: @VonC I do not believe that the definition of the language in EBNF can be correct, and yet if you write code that meets that definition it doesn't compile, or work correctly. I think the Google go people need to introduce carriage return into their ENBF definitions if they want them to be correct.

Comment: @VonC Maybe they should stop using EBNF if it cannot be used to define an if statement correctly.

Comment: @Scooter but wouldn't that ("introduce carriage return") force them to explain in which *context* to use that "carriage return"? How would you do that in a *context free* grammar?

Comment: Or they could put a caveat next to to the EBNF for the if statement saying to check elsewhere for extra requirements that the EBNF doesn't reflect.

Comment: @VonC if a carriage return is a part of an if/for/func definition, it would appear that it should be a part of the ENBF for if/for/func. I assume you are talking about having a carriage return as part of the if/for/func EBNF as "introducing context" since it would modify the block definition in certain instances. But in this case, there would need to be an addition definition that wouldn't use the standard block - since that cearly doesn't work.

Comment: @Scooter: a) Citing you: "it looks like the go people have a Language Reference in formal EBNF style that does not fully define the language". So it's not mine, but your idea, that EBNF can "fully define the language", and it is not true. Otherwise as others said before, including mine's - the specs hold as a unit. You cannot deduce the [full] language definition using just a small part of the specs. It doesn't make sense, sorry. And no, CR (actually NL) is *not* part of the if/for/... construct. Please read the specs again. The semicolon injection rules are quite simple, IMHO ;-)

Comment: @jnml Right, it is your idea that it "cannot fully define the language". As I previously mentioned, Wikipedia's entry for EBNF does not mention this. Can you provide any links to support the notion that EBNF doesn't fully define the syntax of a language? Or, just as good, would be a site which uses EBNF to incompletely define their language and puts in a disclaimer (as Google does not) that you will need to read elsewhere to get the full syntax specification?

Comment: @jnml "the specs hold as a unit. You cannot deduce the [full] language definition using just a small part of the specs. It doesn't make sense, sorry. "  What part of the Pascal syntax cannot be deduced from Pascal's EBNF?

Comment: @Scooter: "Can you provide any links to support the notion that EBNF doesn't fully define the syntax of a language?"- No. But by definition, EBNF defines a CF language and is not capable of anything above that. It follows, that EBNF cannot "fully define a PL" as syntax is just one part of a PL definition. Semantics is necessarily included in a PL definition, but the same is, IIUC,  orthogonal to the syntax (per se).

Comment: "What part of the Pascal syntax cannot be deduced from Pascal's EBNF?". The same part which cannot be deduce from Go's EBNF.

Comment: "The same part which cannot be deduce from Go's EBNF"  if-statement =
    if expression then statement [ else statement ] .  is the EBNF for a Pascal if and it needs no separate document to tell you that you have to write it a special way. UNLIKE the EBNF that Google has for their Go language If statement which does not correctly show the syntax.

Comment: I would think that Google Go having an incomplete definition of their statements from EBNF is fairly uncommon. And whether it is or not they should have a statement telling the reader to look elsewhere for more details on how to write an If/Func/For statement.

Comment: @Scooter I don't think it's possible to describe Go's semicolon-insertion rules in EBNF. They aren't context-free, because whether a newline is interpreted as a semicolon depends on the preceding token.